# Is routing table directing traffic through vpn?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, tunneling

I have successfully connected to the Fortinet Vpn using Openfortivpn but my traffic remains being routed int the same way.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and when I connect via the terminal I get the following log messages:

> ```
> INFO: Connected to gateway.
> INFO: Authenticated.
> INFO: Remote gateway has allocated a VPN.
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Got addresses: [10.212.134.200], ns [0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0]
> INFO: Interface ppp0 is UP.
> INFO: Setting new routes...
> INFO: Adding VPN nameservers...
> INFO: Tunnel is up and running.
> ```

For some reason there seem to be multiple Got Addresses logs, that might be why my routing table looks different from the one I have found online:

```
> Kernel IP routing table Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref
> Use Iface default _gateway 0.0.0.0 UG 600 0 0 wlp3s0 
> 1dot1dot1dot1.c 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 ppp0 
> link-local 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 1000 0 0 virbr0
> 172.16.0.0 telix-ThinkPad- 255.255.0.0 UG 0 0 0 ppp0
> 172.31.0.0 telix-ThinkPad- 255.255.255.248 UG 0 0 0 ppp0
> 172.31.1.0 telix-ThinkPad- 255.255.255.240 UG 0 0 0 ppp0
> 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 600 0 0 wlp3s0
> 192.168.122.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 virbr0
> 192.168.229.0 telix-ThinkPad- 255.255.255.0 UG 0 0 0 ppp0
> 192.168.230.0 telix-ThinkPad- 255.255.255.0 UG 0 0 0 ppp0
> 192.168.231.0 telix-ThinkPad- 255.255.255.0 UG 0 0 0 ppp0
> 206.165.205.130 _gateway 255.255.255.255 UGH 0 0 0 wlp3s0
```

When I check the traffic using `sudo tcp -i ppp0` I get nothing, so this has lead me to believe that there must be routing table problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pppd` probably did not add route to direct traffic to the VPN interface (say, `ppp0`). You can check the name of the VPN interface by this cmd `ifconfig`. After successfully running the command/GUI to connect to the VPN, you will see an extra interface (normally `ppp0`). Now, you can try running this command to force all traffic of your machine go through the VPN interface:

```
sudo route add default ppp0
```

Note that, this command add a temporary route to the routing table. As soon as you turn off your VPN connection, the route is deleted. Every time you connect to the VPN server, you will need to run the above command again.

Hope this help.

Comment: Much appreciated @weefwefwqg3!

Comment: You're welcome. Did it work for you? if not, you can also try `sudo route add default gw X.X.X.X` with `X.X.X.X` is the IP address of the VPN you are connecting to. Haha, got `-1` for answering a so-called off topic question. What a funny community! cheers!

Comment: Yeah I know! I tried to up vote you, but I can't yet. Sometimes I feel Stackoverflow is too stringent. Anyway, I haven't tried it yet, but thank you so much for helping!